# how to make the editor gutter show lines changes against another branch, such as origin/main?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

As shown in the screen cap below, the gutter to the left of the editor shows line numbers and color indicators for which lines have changed (and what kind of change):

[image]

It shows the changes against the current `HEAD`.

How could I make it show changes against another branch, such as main or even a remote branch such as origin/main?

For example, if the same change was already made on origin/mainline, I want no color indicator to show at all.

Thank you!!!!!

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You can use "Compare with" feature but it requires a manual action, it won't display in the gutter.

Comment: There is a similar request, please feel free to vote:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-24398

Comment: @RuslanKuleshov there's no need to wait. The Git Scope plugin works so well you would think it was native. All commands, e.g. ⌘D / get diff of cur file, works against whatever branch is selected in the Git Scope tool window.  Kevin, have you not tried it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### You can do this with the [Git Scope](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10083-git-scope) plugin

It adds a `Git Scope` tool window that looks much like the built-in Git tool window (or the Commit tool window if you have the Git non-modal interface enabled). In the `Git Scope` window you can select a different branch to be the basis of file change indicators: [image: screen cap showing Git-Scope tool window]

Not only that:

- If you click on the color indicators, you can see the actual diff against the chosen branch.
- The `Git Scope` window shows all changed files against the chosen branch (much like the built-in git window shows all changed files against `HEAD`).
- As with the built-in window, you can right click on any file to or press ⌘D to see a full diff, or the `Show Diff` button to iterate over all file changes.
- In fact, as far as I can tell, Git-Scope changes the diff context for even the built-in commands for showing the diff of the currently open file.
- The `Git Scope` window has a toggle button to conveniently switch back and forth between normal mode (diffs against `HEAD`) and the `Git Scope` mode.

Comment: God bless you, I wishing for this for a while now.

Comment: Any other option that is compatible with PyCharm 2022.2.3?